# Console.log doesn't print anything inside forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise, console.log

I'm playing with Polkadot API to get a list of active validators in the network and write this code:

[Open in Polkadot js sandbox https://polkadot.js.org](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#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)

```js
// All code is wrapped within an async closure,
// allowing access to api, hashing, types, util.
// (async ({ api, hashing, types, util }) => {
//   ... any user code is executed here ...
// })();

const [chain, nodeName, nodeVersion] = await Promise.all([
  api.rpc.system.chain(),
  api.rpc.system.name(),
  api.rpc.system.version()
]);

console.log(`Connected to chain ${chain} using ${nodeName} v${nodeVersion}`);

// Retrieve active validators
const [validators] = await Promise.all([
  api.query.session.validators()
]);

if (validators && validators.length > 0) {

  // Map staking stats to validators
  const validatorStaking = await Promise.all(
    validators.map(authorityId => api.query.staking.ledger(authorityId))
  );

  var rank = 1;
  validators.forEach((authorityId, index) => {

    // Get staking stats for current validator
    var validator = JSON.parse(validatorStaking[index])

    // Get nominators, then print information
    Promise.all([
      api.query.staking.stakers(validator.stash)
    ]).then(nominators => {
      return nominators
    }).then(function(nominators) {

      // Iterate over nominators list
      var total = 0
      var nominatorsList = ''
      nominators[0].others.forEach((nominator, index) => {
        total = total + parseInt(nominator.value)
        nominatorsList += '    [' + (index + 1) + '] ' + nominator.who + ' => ' + parseFloat(nominator.value / 1000000000000000).toFixed(3) + ' DOT\n'
      })

      console.log('\n[ ' + rank + ' ] Validator: ' + authorityId.toString())
      console.log( ' -> Controller: ' + authorityId.toString() )
      console.log( ' -> Stash: ' + validator.stash)
      console.log( ' -> Self bonded: ' + parseFloat(validator.total / 1000000000000000).toFixed(3) + ' DOT')
      console.log( ' -> Bonded by nominators: ' + parseFloat(total / 1000000000000000).toFixed(3) + ' DOT' )
      console.log( ' -> Total Bonded: ' + (parseFloat((total) / 1000000000000000) + parseFloat((validator.total) / 1000000000000000) ).toFixed(3) + ' DOT' )
      console.log( ' -> Nominators:' )
      console.log( nominatorsList )

      rank++
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  })
}
```

The code run as expected in https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/js, printing some useful information about the validators.

I want to execute the same code in my Polkadot full node so I modify my code using the first example of the api documentation:

```js
// @ts-check
// Required imports
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');

async function main () {

  //
  // Initialise the provider to connect to the local polkadot node
  //
  const provider = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9944');

  // Create the API and wait until ready
  const api = await ApiPromise.create(provider);

  // Retrieve the chain & node information
  const [chain, nodeName, nodeVersion] = await Promise.all([
    api.rpc.system.chain(),
    api.rpc.system.name(),
    api.rpc.system.version()
  ]);

  console.log(`Connected to chain ${chain} using ${nodeName} v${nodeVersion}`);

  // Retrieve active validators
  const [validators] = await Promise.all([
    api.query.session.validators()
  ]);

  if (validators && validators.length > 0) {

    // Map staking stats to validators
    const validatorStaking = await Promise.all(
      validators.map(authorityId => api.query.staking.ledger(authorityId))
    );

    var rank = 1;
    validators.forEach((authorityId, index) => {

      // Get staking stats for current validator
      var validator = JSON.parse(validatorStaking[index])

      // Get nominators, then print information
      Promise.all([
        api.query.staking.stakers(validator.stash)
      ]).then(nominators => {
        return nominators
      }).then(function(nominators) {

        // Iterate over nominators list
        var total = 0
        var nominatorString = ''
        nominators[0].others.forEach((nominator, index) => {
          total = total + parseInt(nominator.value)
          nominatorString += '    [' + (index + 1) + '] ' + nominator.who + ' => ' + parseFloat(nominator.value / 1000000000000000).toFixed(3) + ' DOT\n'
        })

        console.log('\n[ ' + rank + ' ] Validator: ' + authorityId.toString())        
        console.log( ' -> Controller: ' + authorityId.toString() )
        console.log( ' -> Stash: ' + validator.stash)
        console.log( ' -> Self bonded: ' + parseFloat(validator.total / 1000000000000000).toFixed(3) + ' DOT')
        console.log( ' -> Bonded by nominators: ' + parseFloat(total / 1000000000000000).toFixed(3) + ' DOT' )
        console.log( ' -> Total Bonded: ' + (parseFloat((total) / 1000000000000000) + parseFloat((validator.total) / 1000000000000000) ).toFixed(3) + ' DOT' )        
        console.log( ' -> Nominators:' )
        console.log( nominatorString )

        rank++
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    })
  }
}

main().catch(console.error).finally(() => process.exit());
```

The modified code runs without problem taking the information from the local polkadot node. The problem is that the console.logs inside the forEach statement doesn't print anything.

What i'm doing wrong? The first code runs perfectly in the Polkadot website showing this output:

```
Connected to chain Alexander using parity-polkadot v0.4.4

[ 1 ] Validator: 5GeJHN5EcUGPoa5pUwYkXjymoDVN1DJHsBR4UGX4XRAwK1Ez
 -> Controller: 5GeJHN5EcUGPoa5pUwYkXjymoDVN1DJHsBR4UGX4XRAwK1Ez
 -> Stash: 5DuiZFa184E9iCwbh4WjXYvJ88NHvWJbS8SARY8Ev1YEqrri
 -> Self bonded: 500.000 DOT
 -> Bonded by nominators: 3.384 DOT
 -> Total Bonded: 503.384 DOT
 -> Nominators:
    [1] 5CpSTAh8e8Z8Xq47TDLJz8pn9wTWJ5o47F9bM5McP2kFggf9 => 0.002 DOT
    [2] 5EKv5WtPrm3oE56XojPtAQR8wtiHVNJ9BaM8StPKgzqPPXpG => 0.100 DOT
    [3] 5FeQ1oB2ek2LQGY2SyaHU7UftdwZLT3TNif8ksKvxES1joiD => 0.148 DOT
    [4] 5EEe1QBewqUkVoUT6rmMWtxktcAXcjadFiB6zNwdAgkvM6pw => 0.100 DOT
    [5] 5GryLKn5HrFGXhSQTcgAWEoaFqBGov2voUfawF5nVcsQs8QR => 0.100 DOT
    [6] 5F6is3DBLJreMEpDCN1mDG6RAAHuhGyPx6rzxZ52BfVB9822 => 0.100 DOT
    [7] 5CSopKqGJAyUyAwvxJvwz5NnEZe9eTNTxdXnLDdgSBXrwV36 => 0.148 DOT
    [8] 5Gxn6e7xFYWFS4WZGrHVq7tLkUCTwDVzDJGttweMFAM2s1os => 0.100 DOT
    [9] 5GZBbVudNqkyrwFr1B89N2kCKj5hSwphX8VyvCsWTNg2vb8k => 0.140 DOT
    [10] 5FJArxJ2965RVmBtbUxSLPHMMW2Hkd39akTbRBvRqqffewqk => 0.180 DOT
    [11] 5CHs11e7oWTX7jSW3A6qHJjGdw2BoQGrocoXTzmYoh9aTSZ5 => 0.100 DOT
    [12] 5FCUUyVRBv1M3sjkKhsPEqjmftt43NRyH1fkbiKXswJwRQei => 0.388 DOT
    [13] 5GsZJprFgwyLXiv91XBbNR6xMJU7poEkCCgnKRk8Y7RNa5mY => 0.100 DOT
    [14] 5DqrgoGUigk6GKWE4cnxiqWqBFbDbD1dnEhcSCNBgibsveoS => 0.258 DOT
    [15] 5GDftAqfcQNSnVuKviALyxiDTRP1kSGPKHpdueSz1gLTfgS2 => 0.128 DOT
    [16] 5E7ibdmaVkV1jWbj3HPev2xPstRf17kFjQCjfnGU8iTNWKGq => 1.000 DOT
    [17] 5DfnhKjxZaaUcPW1VYuHfBTuGaE9Fg1mDAnTQera45WCLv8N => 0.018 DOT
    [18] 5CPHNVVLQ5b9esNbT9ZHZiPFvjfw2xbNf83CxP2nmA6yZQDM => 0.000 DOT
    [19] 5FyGYnwUur577KDcdkyyMouprFweXgnQc5KQggJ2QD74MgkC => 0.275 DOT

[ 2 ] Validator: 5DPW1n4q2THUjKGj3QKkcqdh6oxY1bmLsSQ7t8FuiuNtRv4S
 -> Controller: 5DPW1n4q2THUjKGj3QKkcqdh6oxY1bmLsSQ7t8FuiuNtRv4S
 -> Stash: 5DqAzPeXXmBS8p6TjtvjWZPRkqkmeT15KqXoYAg2LShgu9pd
 -> Self bonded: 500.000 DOT
 -> Bonded by nominators: 1.333 DOT
 -> Total Bonded: 501.333 DOT
 -> Nominators:
    [1] 5FHKn8H5L2s5Sar3uhpLoUMqto9J5JWYXNUio7dRKr8E84zu => 0.100 DOT
    [2] 5E4zTNJRPNu9afjsMEjK88MTxVBzXEn55Exf1pW1rW25ysA9 => 0.177 DOT
    [3] 5DPyJoPbVB2PcviCfBxaALj6aj33cS4smAsFz8qPSvKdcVFB => 0.100 DOT
    [4] 5DsS6mvvg3CBxQsvoPFEsSsJB9T9mz13g9GqTnhj4u8KZStV => 0.120 DOT
    [5] 5E9WSxB1YQTJQC7xxirsYKkjMw8vTUffkcLdmWkNPmAPgiA1 => 0.440 DOT
    [6] 5HBbUGki4VmLb8AJ9mHEe8vK9ayiQUfpCanePt21EJchu3oS => 0.295 DOT
    [7] 5ELanwMU5rC4tCGuEdxERA5tdyPnBEC32oLvsLfsWFDsTyK7 => 0.100 DOT
...
```

The second one only shows this output when executed with nodejs v10.16.0:

```
Connected to chain Alexander using parity-polkadot v0.4.4
```

Comment: Do you have anything in `validators`?

Comment: Yes, validator contains an array of address mapped to validator staking statistics object.

Comment: OK, then the next possible point of failure is `Promise.all([api.query.staking.stakers(validator.stash) ]).then(nominators => { return nominators }).then(function(nominators) {` - could it maybe not get return anything there?

Comment: The problem is in Promise.all, the code inside ".then" is not being executed.

Comment: api.query.staking.stakers(validator.stash) returns Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Simplified, you have `var rank = 1; validators.forEach(() => { Promise.all(somePromises).then(... rank++) })` That's async activity inside a synchronous `forEach()`. Therefore the incrementing of `rank` depends on the settlement order of `somePromises`, which will not necessarily reflect the original order of `somePromises`. You need to consider carefully whether or not this is acceptable.

Comment: Why `const [validators] = await Promise.all([api.query.session.validators()])` and not `const validators = await api.query.session.validators()`?

Comment: Similarly, why `Promise.all([api.query.staking.stakers(validator.stash)]).then(nominators => ...)` and not `var nominators = await api.query.staking.stakers(validator.stash);`?

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: Hi Roamer, thank you very much for your corrections. I have many to learn with async code in javascript (that's why i used Promise.all instead of simply 
 const validators = await api.query.session.validators() ) :-). The point that the rank variable may be not reflect the real order is not acceptable to me. I'm going t rewrite the code not using mixed async / sync code.

Comment: you shouldn't use the name Promise for the bluebird module :var Promise = require('bluebird') (jshint W079

Comment: here you are not returning a promise and breaks the promises chain :     then(nominators => {
        return nominators
      })